# Regex get everything after specific matched parenthesis based on value inside them

Tags: c#, regex, regexp-replace

So I have a list of vinyl records that I own, and I am trying to remove some text from their results off of discog, the strings can look something like this;

```
Artist - Title (12") (Warner Bros - WB1210)
Artist - Title (12", Promo) (Warner Bros - WB1212)
Artist - Title (Summer Mix) (12", Promo) (Warner Bros - WB1444)
Artist - Title (12", LP Album) (Warner Bros- - WB9449)
Artist - Title (12", Red) (Warner Bros - WB1211)
Artist - Title
```

I want to remove the last set of parenthesis so they read;

```
Artist - Title (12")
Artist - Title (12", Promo)
Artist - Title (Summer Mix) (12", Promo)
Artist - Title (12", LP Album)
Artist - Title (12", Red)
Artist - Title
```

I have tried this regex pattern, with no luck;

```
(?<=\(12"(.*)\)[ ]).*
```

If I just use (?<=(12").*) everything after 12" is highlighted, so I assumed add (.*)) would get everything between 12" and the closing parenthesis, obviously it is not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something simple like,

```
(.*) \(
```

See it working on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aJline/1).

---

To handle the newly added case where there are no parens at all, you can just use code. If there is no match, just dump the original string. I wrote up a little code snippet using your sample strings.

```
string[] testStrings = new[] { "Artist - Title (12\") (Warner Bros - WB1210)", "Artist - Title (12\", Promo) (Warner Bros - WB1212)", "Artist - Title (Summer Mix) (12\", Promo) (Warner Bros - WB1444)", "Artist - Title (12\", LP Album) (Warner Bros- - WB9449)", "Artist - Title (12\", Red) (Warner Bros - WB1211)", "Artist - Title" };
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(.*) \(");
foreach (var s in testStrings)
{
    Match match = regex.Match(s);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : s);
}
```

This outputs

```
Artist - Title (12")
Artist - Title (12", Promo)
Artist - Title (Summer Mix) (12", Promo)
Artist - Title (12", LP Album)
Artist - Title (12", Red)
Artist - Title
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this (.*)(?=[ ]\() which captures the text leaving out the last open parentheses. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, there is a problem, if there is no parentheses at all it shows zero matches, how do I get the opposite and match the other end of the line in order to .replace?

Comment: In this case, you don't need to edit the regex. You can just use code to test matches and change the output based on the result. I added some code to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To match the parenthesis at the end and replace them with an empty string, you could use:

```
\s*\([^()]*\)[^()]*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `\([^()]*\)` Match from an opening till closing parenthesis
- `[^()]*` Match optional chars other than `(` and `)`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FBtnlS/1)